# Android - Override method from higher API version and supporting lower API version

Tags: java, android

I'd like to listen for a long key press in my Android application, and from Android 2.0 there is a method

```
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

to override. But what can I do if my app absolutely has to support API 4 (Android 1.6)? I know that I can call API methods with reflection, but I'm pretty sure that I cannot override with reflection.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just remove `@Override` annotation above the method? Android 1.6 would ignore it, 2.0 would still interpret it correctly.

Comment: overriding the function isn't the difficult part... this kind of event requires the use of super.onKeyLongPress() inside of it in order to correctly handle the chain of events.  Android <2.0 will choke on the super.onKeyLongPress() because it does not exist and there is no way to call super.whatever() with reflection in Java.  I am stuck trying to figure out a way to get this same kind of thing to work for API 3 and I am at a loss, too.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to write two implementations of your custom view class, say:

```
MyCustomViewBasic extends View {
    private MySharedImplementation impl;
}

MyCustomViewKeyLongPress extends View {
    private MySharedImplementation impl;

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Do something exciting
    }
}
```

These two implementations can share as many implementation details as possible, whilst ensuring that anything not available in API level 4 is not in the shared implementation.

Then have two xml layouts, one for API level 4 and one for API level 4 and above. Use MyCustomViewBasic in the layout for API level 4 and MyCustomViewKeyLongPress in the one for API level 4 and above

Comment: unfortunately I'd like to do this for the activity